# Links not working when deployed on IIS 5.0

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an asp.net2.0 application with a treeview control for navigation on my site. the application works fine with development server but when i deploy my site on IIS 5.0, the links stop working after the first click on any link.

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: Here is some code...

The urls are stored in this format "~/TopControls/Search.aspx"

public static string ResolveUrls(string Url)
        {

            if (Url.StartsWith("~"))

                return (HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath +
                        Url.Substring(1)).Replace("//", "/");

The code in Treeview_SelectedNodeChanged goes like this.....

                string Path = selectedNode.Path;
                string url = Utilities.ResolveUrls(Path);
                Response.Redirect(url);

Answer (score 0):

Since the link functionality is a browser function, I'm going to assume that by not working you mean that the links are incorrect, not that they fail to fire.  The most likely scenario is that your links are absolute paths rather than relative paths and your web site isn't published at the root of the web server.  It works in development because in the development server it is at the root.  Check to make sure that your links are correct -- best to make them relative or, if using server-side controls, make sure that you use the tilde mapping to substitute the virtual path of the site.

Comment: The same code works on another IIS 5.0 server, so i guess it is some permission issue. All button clicks that cause post back seem to stop responding.